# Кнопка "поделиться" неправильно отображается

Tags: java, android

Почему то рядом с кнопкой "поделиться" в баре отображается одна из иконок из списка для расшаривания. Как ее убрать?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fulldesc, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
        ShareActionProvider MenuSAP = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        MenuSAP.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
        return true;
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Просто нашел это замечательное приложение! Посмотри здесь: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=");
        return shareIntent;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это ожидаемое [поведение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42499648/3212712), описанное в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html#rankings):

> The share action provider retains a ranking for each share target, based on how often the user chooses each one. The more often a user chooses a target, the higher its rank; the most-commonly used target appears in the app bar as the default target.

TL/DR:

Самое популярное приложение для шаринга будет отображаться рядом с иконкой `share`. Засим, если вы этого не хотите, то надо отказаться от такого способа и делать всё вручную:

Убрать провайдер из меню:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

Вручную создать интент:

```
private Intent createShareIntent(){
    Intent actionsend=new Intent();
    actionsend.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    actionsend.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Please Download Jua Leader App From :  http://mstarsinnovations.com");
    actionsend.setType("text/plain");
    return Intent.createChooser(actionsend,"Share The Jua Leader Using");
}
```

Повесить слушатель нажатий на меню:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch(item.getMenuId()) {
    case R.id.share:
      Intent shareIntent = createShareIntent();
      startActivity(shareIntent);
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```